# Loop through asynchronous calls, each waiting for the previous to complete JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I would like to loop through a list of asynchronous calls, but each iteration of the loop waits for the previous iteration to finish executing before starting the next. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use es6 async await

Comment: es8 but yeah like brk said use await :)

Comment: You are looking for https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it using async await!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result and status of the calls in a list. Whenever a call completes, it marks its status as COMPLETE in the status list and store its result in the result list.

At the end of each call, check that whether status of all the calls is complete or not. If complete then you can call your subroutine to loop through the result list of the calls.